# Understanding complete graph example in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to Tikz and trying to understand (and modify) this 16-node complete graph example from texample.net

```
% A complete graph
% Author: Quintin Jean-NoÃ«l
% <http://moais.imag.fr/membres/jean-noel.quintin/>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: A complete graph
:Tags: Foreach;Graphs;To paths
:Author: Jean-NoÃ«l Quintin
:Slug: complete-graph
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary[topaths]
% A counter, since TikZ is not clever enough (yet) to handle
% arbitrary angle systems.
\newcount\mycount
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  %the multiplication with floats is not possible. Thus I split the loop in two.
  \foreach \number in {1,...,8}{
      % Computer angle:
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by -1
  \multiply\mycount by 45
        \advance\mycount by 0
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.25cm] (N-\number) at (\the\mycount:5.4cm) {};
    }
  \foreach \number in {9,...,16}{
      % Computer angle:
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by -1
  \multiply\mycount by 45
        \advance\mycount by 22.5
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.25cm] (N-\number) at (\the\mycount:5.4cm) {};
    }
  \foreach \number in {1,...,15}{
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by 1
  \foreach \numbera in {\the\mycount,...,16}{
    \path (N-\number) edge[->,bend right=3] (N-\numbera)  edge[<-,bend
      left=3] (N-\numbera);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code generates the following picture
[image]

I'm trying to understand how the node and edge positions are computed in the picture, so I can modify it to have less or more nodes. I tried doubling the angles to reduce the number of nodes by half, but that gave me a very ugly picture.

Edit: Added what I've changed. Maybe I did something wrong before, but turns out the picture was not so ugly after all

```
% A complete graph
% Author: Quintin Jean-Noël
% <http://moais.imag.fr/membres/jean-noel.quintin/>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: A complete graph
:Tags: Foreach;Graphs;To paths
:Author: Jean-Noël Quintin
:Slug: complete-graph
\end{comment}
\usetikzlibrary[topaths]
% A counter, since TikZ is not clever enough (yet) to handle
% arbitrary angle systems.
\newcount\mycount
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  %the multiplication with floats is not possible. Thus I split the loop in two.
  \foreach \number in {1,...,4}{
      % Computer angle:
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by -1
  \multiply\mycount by 90
        \advance\mycount by 0
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.25cm] (N-\number) at (\the\mycount:5.4cm) {};
    }
  \foreach \number in {5,...,8}{
      % Computer angle:
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by -1
  \multiply\mycount by 90
        \advance\mycount by 45
      \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.25cm] (N-\number) at (\the\mycount:5.4cm) {};
    }
  \foreach \number in {1,...,7}{
        \mycount=\number
        \advance\mycount by 1
  \foreach \numbera in {\the\mycount,...,8}{
    \path (N-\number) edge[->,bend right=3] (N-\numbera)  edge[<-,bend
      left=3] (N-\numbera);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have changed ...

Comment: Welcome! Wouldn't it be easier to start with a somewhat simpler graph if you're new to Ti*k*Z? One where you can visually match the edges drawn to the code, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say I understood the rule but I guess it's simpler to just draw from scratch

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{16}% how many nodes
\node[circle,minimum size=10 cm] (b) {};
\foreach\x in{1,...,\n}{
  \node[minimum size=0.75cm,draw,circle] (n-\x) at (b.{360/\n*\x}){\x};
}
\foreach\x in{1,...,\n}{
  \foreach\y in{1,...,\n}{
    \ifnum\x=\y\relax\else
      \draw (n-\x) edge[->,bend right=3] (n-\y);
    \fi
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is much easier to understand than the example I put in.

Comment: What does the b stand for in b.{360/\n*\x}?

Comment: @Asterix I've put a big circle node to place the smaller ones around it. It is not necessary you can directly place them. I had a similar example by coincidence so worked from it out of laziness.

Comment: @Asterix You might consider drawing the lines on a background layer so that the circular nodes at the bottom are on top of the lines.